# Why would you go to a party without me?

Tags: modal-verbs

Suppose a wife is arguing with her husband over why he didn't take her to the party yesterday.

1. Wife: Why **would** you **go** to **a** party without me? ("a party" refers to any party *at any time*)
2. Wife: Why **would** you **go** to **a** party without me? ("a party" refers to any party only *in the past*)
3. Wife: Why **would** you **go** to **that** party without me? ("that party" refers to the party yesterday)
4. Wife: Why **would** you **have gone** to **a** party without me?
5. Wife: Why **would** you **have gone** to **that** party without me?

Which ones are correct/idiomatic? I think (1) uses *hypothetical* "would". But what about the others? Is "would" *real* or *hypothetical* in them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of them are idiomatic, but they may have slightly different meanings.

Examples 1 and 2 are identical and have the meaning that you give for example 1 rather than 2. The distinction between any time or past time is the distinction between examples 1 and 4.

The distinction between a party in general and a specific party is conveyed by the distinction in determiners, the indefinite article “a” and the specific determiner “that.”

In all the cases, “would” is hypothetical **unless the context requires a different interpretation.**

Comment: Just one more question (although a little off-topic), please: you say sentence (3) in the OP uses *hypothetical* "would". How about the sentence: *how **could** you **go** to **that** party without me*? Is the "could" *hypothetical* here?

Comment: The implication of "could" is that it actually happened.

Comment: But "would" in sentence (3) in the OP doesn't imply that it actually happened and so is *hypothetical*. Am I right?

Comment: As I said in my answer, the normal meaning of "would" in all the sentences is hypothetical. But context is always important. There could be a context in which it would not be hypothetical. For example, if it was known that the husband had gone to the party, then clearly the meaning would not be hypothetical.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit confused. In the given context, why do you think the wife doesn't know whether her husband went to a party yesterday? As far as I can see, the context clearly suggests that the wife does know that her husband went to a party yesterday, and that's what they're arguing about.

Comment: The context clearly suggests that the wife believes. or purports to believe. that her husband went to the party. That does not make it a fact. In any case, I was talking about the sentences. And I said that "would" was hypothetical unless the context suggested otherwise. If you  think the context makes it clear, what is wrong with my answer?